# Typing "git branch" results in "fatal: HEAD not found below refs/heads!"

Tags: git

```
cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/head/master
git branch
fatal: HEAD not found below refs/heads!
```

The branch command is expecting master to be in refs/heads instead of refs/head.  What is the difference between the 2 directories?  Should I just edit my .git/HEAD file to heads instead of head?  I ran "git init && git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/head/master" earlier so I don't see the issue.

Comment: HEAD is a file while refs/heads is directory. HEAD is a symbolic ref which points to a file in refs/heads. Have you run git init?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Yes, should point to some file in refs/heads/. Try to edit it.

Comment: Why do you run the low-level command `git symbolic-ref` at all? Branches are stored under the `refs/heads` directory. `.git/HEAD` is a file and `refs/head` does not exist.

Comment: followed instructions from https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github#adding-a-local-repository-to-github-using-git but made a typo.  I tried editing the HEAD file but now git branch does not display anything.  Should I just start over?

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA "If you’re using Git 2.27.1 or an earlier version […]" – are you running a version older than 2.27.1?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out.  you need to remove all .git files in your base directory and reinitialize using only git init.  Those instructions are telling you to unecessarily link stuff that is already done by git